# Entity Framework Migrations - How to create a Unit Test to Ensure Migrations Model is up to Date?

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, continuous-integration, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I am using continuous integration with TeamCity, NUnit, and Git. I recently migrated (pardon the pun) from FluentMigrator to Entity Framework Migrations. I primarily did this to take advantage of the scaffolding functionality therein.

However, it is potentially possible to check in some changes to source control without having first scaffolded the changes into migrations (imagine the scenario where the application was not run before committing and pushing the commit). I am using a [pre-tested commit workflow](http://www.joergm.com/2011/05/pre-tested-commits-using-git/), so I would like to detect this problem in the pre-test rather than waiting until calling migrate.exe (which would be too late in my workflow and break the "green repository").

My question is, how to create a unit/integration test to detect when the migrations model doesn't match the context model so I can fail the build before attempting to migrate? Do note that I expect it not to match the database and would prefer not to access the database from the test.

I tried this approach:

```
    [Test]
    public void CheckWhetherEntityFrameworkMigrationsContextIsUpToDate()
    {
        Assert.DoesNotThrow(() =>
        {
            CallDatabase();
        });

    }

    private void CallDatabase()
    {
        using (var ctx = new MyContext("SERVER=(local);DATABASE=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True;"))
        {
            var tenant = (from t in ctx.Tenant
                          select t).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

But this will always fail when there are pending migrations (rather than just in the case where the migrations model is not in sync with the context model, which is what I am after).

### Update

I have added a [work item](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1727) on the EntityFramework project for this issue. Hopefully, they will look into adding a way to do this.

Comment: Are you using EF Core? If yes, do you have an equivalent test for it? All the answers below seem to be for pre-core EF.

Comment: @lonix - I believe this was for EF 6 if I recall correctly. And no, I haven't worked with EF in a long time, so don't have an updated test.

Comment: Doh I didn't notice the date, sorry about that :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is some code that will check whether all model changes have been scaffolded to migrations or not.

```
bool HasPendingModelChanges()
{
    // NOTE: Using MigratorScriptingDecorator so changes won't be made to the database
    var migrationsConfiguration = new Migrations.Configuration();
    var migrator = new DbMigrator(migrationsConfiguration);
    var scriptingMigrator = new MigratorScriptingDecorator(migrator);

    try
    {
        // NOTE: Using InitialDatabase so history won't be read from the database
        scriptingMigrator.ScriptUpdate(DbMigrator.InitialDatabase, null);
    }
    catch (AutomaticMigrationsDisabledException)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This works great. However, it should be noted that the Configuration class is the one that is auto-generated by Entity Framework.

Comment: Thanks Brice! Just so people know, this does actually create a new DB connection for some reason and you can adjust the connection by setting the `TargetDatabase` property on the `Migrations.Configuration` class if you need to do this. It took me an embarassingly long time to figure that out.

Comment: How did you get around `'Configuration' is inaccessible due to project level` error when running from Test project?

Comment: @bbodenmiller Make it `public` or use the `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyTests")]` attribute.

Answer (score 11):

In case anybody finds this useful, I test migrations by running all of them against a **test database**, using the following code:

```
[TestClass]
public class MigrationsTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void RunAll()
    {
        var configuration = new Configuration();
        var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
        // back to 0
        migrator.Update("0");
        // up to current
        migrator.Update();
        // back to 0
        migrator.Update("0");
    }
}
```

This tests all `Up` and `Down` migrations, as well as detecting pending changes when automatic migrations is turned off.

**NOTE:** Make sure you run this against a test database. In my case the test project's `app.config` has the connectionString to the test database (just a local SQLExpress instance).

Comment: This isn't a good test. For instance when you forget to drop a field, and in the next downgrade the table is dropped. Then this test will succeed anyway. You need to go up/down per step to be sure they actually work. (Or the migration system should actually check if the model is correct after an upgrade/downgrade).

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as saying it's not a good test. It just does the full chain up and down, but yeah, you can do individual up and down if you like. I didn't come across the situation you mention TBH.

Comment: In order to get this to work for NUnit I had to apply [RunInApplicationDomain] to my test. This attribute can be found at https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit.ApplicationDomain/

Answer (score 5):

I wanted the best of all the answers given here so far so here's what I've come up with:

```
[TestClass()]
public class MigrationsTests
{
    [TestMethod()]
    public void MigrationsUpDownTest()
    {
        // Unit tests don't have a DataDirectory by default to store DB in
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

        // Drop and recreate database
        BoxContext db = new BoxContext();
        db.Database.Delete();

        var configuration = new Migrations.Configuration();
        var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);

        // Retrieve migrations
        List<string> migrations = new List<string>;
        migrations.AddRange(migrator.GetLocalMigrations());

        try
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < migrations.Count; index++)
            {
                migrator.Update(migrations[index]);
                if (index > 0) {
                    migrator.Update(migrations[index - 1]);
                } else {
                    migrator.Update("0"); //special case to revert initial migration
                }
            }

            migrator.Update(migrations.Last());
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Assert.Fail("Should not have any errors when running migrations up and down: " + ex.Errors[0].Message.ToString());
        }

        // Optional: delete database
        db.Database.Delete();
    }

    [TestMethod()]
    public void PendingModelChangesTest()
    {
        // NOTE: Using MigratorScriptingDecorator so changes won't be made to the database
        var migrationsConfiguration = new Migrations.Configuration();
        var migrator = new DbMigrator(migrationsConfiguration);
        var scriptingMigrator = new MigratorScriptingDecorator(migrator);

        try
        {
            // NOTE: Using InitialDatabase so history won't be read from the database
            scriptingMigrator.ScriptUpdate(DbMigrator.InitialDatabase, null);
        }
        catch (AutomaticMigrationsDisabledException)
        {
            Assert.Fail("Should be no pending model changes/migrations should cover all model changes.");
        }
    }
}
```

Couple things worth noting:

- You need to install Entity Framework in your test project
- You need to add `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyTestsProject")]` to the top of your `Configuration` class
- You need to specify an Entity Framework connection string in `App.config` that is only for test project since database will be deleted and recreated frequently - if running on build machine keep in mind that parallel runs could result in conflicts so you may want to change string per build

Answer (score 3):

I think this works better than Pablo Romeo's code. This upgrades and then downgrades one step again to catch missing items in the downgrade scripts.

```
[TestFixture]
class MigrationTest
{
    [Test]
    public void RunAll()
    {
        var configuration = new Configuration();
        var migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);

        // Retrieve migrations
        List<string> migrations = new List<string> {"0"};  // Not sure if "0" is more zero than the first item in list of local migrations
        migrations.AddRange(migrator.GetLocalMigrations());

        migrator.Update(migrations.First());

        // Doe een stapje naar voren, en een stapje terug (www.youtube.com/watch?v=2sg1KAxuWKI)
        // (Dutch pun) meaning: take a small step forward, and a small step back ;)
        for (int index = 0; index < migrations.Count; index++)
        {
            migrator.Update(migrations[index]);
            if (index > 0)
                migrator.Update(migrations[index - 1]);
        }

        migrator.Update(migrations.Last());

        migrator.Update(migrations.First());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please translate that comment to English?

Comment: its a joke but it also explains what the code does, it says: do one step forward and a  step back (its the name of a dutch song). But in reality it goes 2 steps forward and one step back (except the first iteration). For example: it goes to version 0 then version 1, then version 0, then version 2, then version 1, then version 3, then version 2, then version 4 etc.

Comment: How does this actually catch the missing items in the down section?

Comment: Yes! Because if you don't remove it, you will get an exception when you try to update again (as fields/indexes already exist).

Answer (score 2):

EF Core has a pretty straight forward method:

```
myDbContext.Database.Migrate();
```

Comment: That will migrate the database, rather than tell you whether you **should** migrate the database. Also the idea is to detect that inside a unit test.